# infinitisimal part and the directional integral

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, matlab, infinitesimals

In the paper

> A circle detection approach based on Radon Transform by Erman Okman
>   and Gozde B. Akar.

I have a few questions on some basics.

first of all what does

$$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$$

mean, It says it is the infinitisimal part but what does it mean specificly. I guessed it could be a substitution.

an other part is the given the following integral.

$$ g_1(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy$$

what exactly is the directional integral

$$g_1[m] = \sum _n f[m,n] $$

more specifically it says " which are evaluated by taking integral of $g_1(x)$ and  over $[m-0.5, m+0.5]$ and $[n-0.5, n+0.5]$, respectively."

does this mean we do a several integration of the form 
$$ g_1 [m]= \sum_n   \int_{n-0.5} ^{n+0.5} f(m,y)dy$$

and if yes is there a simple way to implement it in matlab. Well I have a discrete Image which means the image is only defined on a grid $[1,\dots,m ]\times [1,\dots n]$. How would the integral look like and how can I integrate over one variable on a function $f(x,y)$ with two variables.

I am happy for any hint. talk to you later

Answer (score 0):

The relation $dx^2=dx^2+dy^2$ was called the characteristic triangle by Leibniz. Here $ds$ is an infinitesimal element of length (i.e. $s$ is the arclength parameter in modern terminology) along a curve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a look into the characteristic Triangle.